# How can I execute a shell command to populate a docker-compose build arg?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using the git commit hash `git rev-parse --short HEAD` for versioning and want to pass that value to my docker image.  How can I execute arbitrary shell commands to populate a build arg in the docker-compose.yml?

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  my_app:
    build:
      args:
        - VERSION=EXECUTE_SHELL_COMMAND_HERE!!
...
```

I know the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#args) say I could set a matching environment variable at runtime

```
VERSION=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD) docker-compose up
```

but am looking for a cleaner way that doesn't require manually setting that environment variable every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this docker compose issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4081) they don't support that:

> Sorry, this is not something we support. Usually, this is done by
>   setting environment variables and using variable substitution inside
>   the Compose file instead.

In the other hand this is an issue from 2016, so could be out of date...